# CORS failed .Net 6.0 Api (Blazor WASM, POST and GET are working)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm getting the following CORS Error when using **PUT** or **DELETE** requests.

[getting this cors error in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHRzT.png)

When i use **POST** or **GET**, requests are working whitout any problems.
On localhost **all** requests types are working, even there are different domains used as well.

Already checked the following:

- Simplified the Rules as much as possible (AllowAny...)
- Checked the Middleware order according to the [official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order)

But still no sucess.

Does anybody has a hint on this?

My Program.cs

```
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Adding Cors default plicy with almost no requirements
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});


builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //Swagger config removed for stackoverflow
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
   //Db Context options removed for stackoverflow
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    //Authentication options removed for stackoverflow
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

//adding repositories and services removed for stackoverflow
//builder.Services.AddScoped....    
//builder.Services.AddSingleton...

var app = builder.Build();

//seed database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    //database seeding removed for stackoverflow
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

//After Routing, before Authorization
app.UseCors();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few investigations and communication with my webhoster, i found the problem as well as a solution for it:

IIS will activate the WebDav Module, wich disables PUT and DELETE requests. To get your requests running could disable WebDav directly in IIS. But at every restart of the application pool WebDav will be enabled again.

See here as well: https://fantinel.dev/dotnet-core-405-error/

So what i did, is to add a web.config file to my .net core api and disabled WebDav there. After this, CORS is working like a charm.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked in our WASM application we build last year. In there I see this:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseCors(policy =>
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for checking your solution. Unfortunately this wasn't the problem. I did found the problem and solution. See comment.