# enable Cors in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I recently use .NET Core 6 and I want to upload file using web API from Jquery. but always get

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource"

error.
Startup.cs Code:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<Views.App.ConnectionStrings>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(Views.App.ConnectionStrings)));
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
        });
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NUXT",
                            builder =>
                            {
                                builder.WithOrigins("*")
                                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                                       .AllowAnyMethod();
                            });
        });

    }
```

and Program.cs Code:

```
using System.Globalization;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("NUXT");
app.UseAuthorization();
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("fa-IR"),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("fa-IR") }
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);    
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273296/7357322

Comment: its not work on .net core 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of WithOrigins("*") I am using AllowAnyOrigin (). And everytning should be in one place Program if you use it instead of startup. And cors is usually used for API, so maybe you don't need add withviews in your code too

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("NUXT", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
}));

builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
.....

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("NUXT");

// app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: i just have problem in file uploading, another api work currectly

Answer (score 1):

Use the prop

```
[EnableCors("NUXT")]
public class algoController : ControllerBase{
}
```

also you can create a CorsMiddleware that added the header to responses

```
    public class CorsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

and use that in the program.cs file after de build, for example:

```
app.UseCorsMiddleware();
```