# How to enable CORS in a C# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, cors

I'm building a C# application for which i have to update in database and that needs to make requests to an API running on a different domain. However, when I try to make these requests, I'm getting CORS errors.

I've read about CORS and understand that it's a security feature that browsers use to prevent cross-domain requests, but I'm not sure how to enable it in my C# application.

Can someone please explain how to enable CORS in a C# application and provide an example of how to make a cross-domain request using CORS? Thanks in advance!

I had tried to install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" from package manager but is not working.

Comment: Did you search for `asp.net enable cors` and read this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0. Btw, you really want to specify if ots the .NET Framework or Core (or 5, 6, or 7)

Comment: "[it's] not working" is not a a sufficiently detailed problem description. Please try agian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enable Cors in .NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392530/enable-cors-in-net-core-6)

Comment: _it's a security feature that browsers use to prevent cross-domain requests_. No, quite the opposite: CORS relaxes restrictions. That's a common misconception, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using (var client = new HttpClient())

Comment: Add this to your code

Comment: This is an incorrect solution. First it has nothing to do with CORS. Second you should not be creating a new `HttpClient` instance with each request, nor should you be routinely `Dispose`-ing them

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't only post code as an answer, but _also_ provide an explanation about what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Can you [edit] your answer to include this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy And Paste In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();

// U Can Filter Here
}));
```

Then write this, also in Program.cs. But write it in the correct order, after `app.UseRouting();` and before `app.UseAuthentication();` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

Answer (score -1):

In C# MVC application we can add **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** NuGet package. After successfully installing this package use the below line in a controller,

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

And, EnableCORS before defining APIs like:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", methods: "*", headers: "*")]
public int GetId(int id)
{
     return id;
}
```